# Why my 500gb SSD has only 477056 inodes?

Tags: debian, filesystems, ssd, inode

```
Filesystem        Inodes   IUsed     IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev             4030305     685   4029620    1% /dev
tmpfs            4040316    1252   4039064    1% /run
/dev/sdb1         477056  476282       774  100% /
tmpfs            4040316     399   4039917    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs            4040316       5   4040311    1% /run/lock
tmpfs               1024      17      1007    2% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1      122101760 3865680 118236080    4% /media/2TB
/dev/loop2         62342   62342         0  100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
/dev/loop0         26205   26205         0  100% /snap/telegram-desktop/2198
/dev/loop1           249     249         0  100% /snap/whatsdesk/20
/dev/loop3         10476   10476         0  100% /snap/go/6727
/dev/loop4         11573   11573         0  100% /snap/core20/634
/dev/loop5         12826   12826         0  100% /snap/core/10185
/dev/loop6         27807   27807         0  100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145
/dev/loop7         10779   10779         0  100% /snap/core18/1932
/dev/loop8         62411   62411         0  100% /snap/wickrpro/495
/dev/loop9         62411   62411         0  100% /snap/wickrme/430
/dev/loop10          472     472         0  100% /snap/snapd/9721
tmpfs             808063      28    808035    1% /run/user/1000
/dev/loop11        63811   63811         0  100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1513 
root@desktop:/# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.1G  1.8M  3.1G   1% /run
/dev/sdb1       465G  214G  247G  47% /
tmpfs            16G  727M   15G   5% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           4.0M     0  4.0M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1       1.8T  1.6T  164G  91% /media/2TB
/dev/loop2       63M   63M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
/dev/loop0      179M  179M     0 100% /snap/telegram-desktop/2198
/dev/loop1      639M  639M     0 100% /snap/whatsdesk/20
/dev/loop3       92M   92M     0 100% /snap/go/6727
/dev/loop4       61M   61M     0 100% /snap/core20/634
/dev/loop5       98M   98M     0 100% /snap/core/10185
/dev/loop6      163M  163M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145
/dev/loop7       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1932
/dev/loop8      449M  449M     0 100% /snap/wickrpro/495
/dev/loop9      449M  449M     0 100% /snap/wickrme/430
/dev/loop10      31M   31M     0 100% /snap/snapd/9721
tmpfs           3.1G   44K  3.1G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/loop11      65M   65M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1513
```

Why my 2TB SSD has 122101760 inodes but my 500GB SSD has 477056?
I'm running out of inodes while my SSD is only half-full.

Comment: Your 2TB disk has one iNode per 16KB of disk, which is the default ratio for ext3/ext4 partitions. But your 500GB disk only has one iNode per 1048KB of disk. That's not too many small files, that's an initial config issue. Would you know (a) what partitioned the disk, and (b) which file system was created on it. (My NTFS partitions have an iNode per 2KB, which is way too many.)

Comment: OMG, I think I did not select one inode per 1048KB, I don't know. Thank you I understood finally the inodes issue.

Answer (score 5):

In Linux system, filenames are just, so to say, links to the real files (inodes). When you create a file, even a symbolic link, you reserve an inode. You are taking inode to create a file. So while you are setting up a filesystem in Linux, you (system) allocate the number of inodes and size per inode. In your case, 465 GB (499289948160 Bytes) filesystem is divided to 477056 (number, count) inodes. It means that PER INODE you have 499289948160 / 477056 = 1046606 Bytes (~1 MB)

When you create links (`ln`), text files which requires only Kilobytes or even Bytes of storage, they take one inode, and because each inode is 1 MB they are running out too soon.

So actually, you have used 214 GB, but because you have a lot of SMALL files (inodes) which is normal, you are out of inode numbers!

To solve this problem you can re-format your system (**but note that you will need to backup your data first, and then restore the data from a backup**).

```
mke2fs -t ext4 -I 1024 /dev/sdX1
```

If you choose 1024, 499289948160 (the total bytes of your ssd) will be divided to 1024 and you will get huge number of inodes and they will not be running out that soon.

Comment: Thank you for a detailed explanation, I have to pay more attention on my next installation of debian at the time of partitioning.

Comment: _"When you create a file, even a hardlinks for the same file, you reserve an inode"_ -- no, **hard** links don't need inodes, they're just names in the directory, like the "original" file name. **Symbolic** links do take inodes, in a low level sense they're "files" of their own, they have owner information and access bits (though not used), dates distinct from the target, and contents (the link text).

Answer (score 0):

Some filesystem types like XFS will create inodes on-demand, and might leave the inodes of deleted files around for a while so that they can be quickly reused if needed.

If your smaller SSD has a XFS filesystem but the larger one has a classic-style filesystem like ext4, this could be normal and harmless.